# ArcGIS Online Symbology from related Table

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, table

I have not found a method of accomplishing this:

I have a layer (and related tables) in SQL server hosted on ArcGIS Server 10.6.1 being consumed in ArcGIS Online Web Map.

All this works great but I want to be able to symbolize the features based off the related table fields not the layer fields themselves. I cannot find a way to do this. (or if its even possible).

There is a [GeoNet thread](https://community.esri.com/thread/164994#comment-577102) that describes this but the poster who originally posted a workaround was not clear and then changes his answer.... does anyone have a working method that can accomplish this?

Comment: Here is a link talking about viewing related data in ArcGIS Online which just released: It might help you out https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/visualizing-related-data-with-join-features-in-arcgis-online/

Comment: looked promising but I do not think this is relevant for related tables.

Comment: You will have to use a hosted feature layer and this tool can create a view layer from the parent layer with the related layer and then from the blog posted you can render data based on information in related records. If you are using Portal in Online I think using Collaborations might work and from the hosted layer spun up from collaborations could work with this scenario.

Comment: the source data is coming form arcgis server hosted in sql server environment. I cannot use hosted feature services(layer)